# AttributeError: 'BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions' object has no attribute 'transpose'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, fast-ai

I am fine tuning a pretrained BERT model from transformers (Hugginface).

```
class CustomBertTokenizer(BaseTokenizer):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, max_seq_len=128, **kwargs):
        self._pretrained_tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_seq_len = max_seq_len

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

    def tokenize(self, t):
        """Limits the maximum sequence length"""
        return ["[CLS]"] + self._pretrained_tokenizer.tokenize(t)[:self.max_seq_len - 2] + ["[SEP]"]


bert_tok = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(tok_func=CustomBertTokenizer(bert_tok, max_seq_len=128), pre_rules=[], post_rules=[])
vocab = Vocab(list(bert_tok.vocab.keys()))

data_bunch = TextDataBunch.from_df('./', bs=1, include_eos=False, include_bos=False, train_df=train_df, test_df=test_df, valid_df=val_df, tokenizer=tokenizer, vocab=vocab)

learner = Learner(data_bunch, model, metrics=[accuracy])
```

Oncalling learner.fit_one_cycle(1), i am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-304-158e79851ed2> in <module>
----> 1 learner.fit_one_cycle(1)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastai/layers.py in __call__(self, input, target, **kwargs)
    232 
    233     def __call__(self, input:Tensor, target:Tensor, **kwargs)->Rank0Tensor:
--> 234         input = input.transpose(self.axis,-1).contiguous()
    235         target = target.transpose(self.axis,-1).contiguous()
    236         if self.floatify: target = target.float()

AttributeError: 'BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions' object has no attribute 'transpose'
```

I think this is some incompatibility issue since i am using pytorch and i saw tensors in the error trace.